# How to make Capybara/Poltergeist wait for js initiated navigation to finish?

Tags: javascript, testing, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have a test that checks if, after the user chooses an option from the autocomplete suggestions, the path has changed. I'm testing with Capybara on Poltergeist. However, presumably because I'm triggering the page change trough JS, I have to use a sleep statement now in order to wait for the page to finish loading, which of course isn't ideal.

This is the js:

```
window.location.href = suggestion.url;
```

And this is the test:

```
sleep 1# Allow the time to navigate
expect(current_path).to eq(arg1)
```

where arg1 is the expected page url.

It works fine with sleep, but the reasons why this isn't optimal are obvious. How to make the test smarter and have it wait for the navigation to take place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the `eq` matcher with current_path (with most Capybara things actually), use the have_current_path matcher

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(arg1)
```

which will utilize the automatic wait/retry behavior built into Capybara

Answer (score 0):

Test for something on the new page (that doesn't exist on the page where you are navigating from) and rspec will keep looking until it appears (as long as its within the default wait limit), then check for your path e.g. do something like this first

```
expect(page).to have_selector("a.testclass", text: "Some link on your new page")
```

Then your path test:

```
expect(current_path).to eq(arg1)
```

Comment: I figured something like that would do it, but it's pretty hacky, wouldn't you agree? And then the test might fail even though it navigated correct, giving the wrong impression.

Comment: Yeah, I find myself doing things like this a lot when there is a lot of JS in an app so it seems "normal" to me. Tom Walpole's answer looks like the best fit in this case.